# How to prevent the opening of the YouTube application in a iOs?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have a slider with youtube players. I use lazyload technologies with **data-src=**, when the slider swiped, **data-src=** is changing on **src=**. And then,When an attribute src is added, an YT application is opened. I tried everything, some params in src iframe, example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BoS0UrM-zQs/?
enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1&modestbranding=1&autoplay=0&controls=0" 
data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BoS0UrM-zQs" type="text/html" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

but it doesn't work.